# chocoletey install jdk8 never ends

Tags: chocolatey

I'm trying to use the windows package manager chocolatey to install jdk8, but it takes forever, powershell just print out the following and never ends:

```
jdk8 v8.0.66
 Downloading JDK from http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u66-b18/jdk-8u66-windows-x64.ex
e
```

I copy the link and try to open in browser, what I got is an error page from oracle saying that I must agree to the OTN license terms blah blah ...

Is there a way to get around this?? Why doesn't chocolatey just fail??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with terminology - why doesn't the ***package*** just fail. Chocolatey itself just releases over to the package to do the install. If the package is badly behaved (and it's not a badly behaved scenario that Chocolatey yet covers), then you will see behavior such as what you are seeing.

### Chocolatey Execution Timeout

Chocolatey has a default timeout of 45 minutes for a package install. You can change the default timeout, see `choco install -h` or https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsReference#default-options-and-switches:

```
--execution-timeout=VALUE
  CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds - Override the default execution
  timeout in the configuration of 2700 seconds.
```

You can also set the value in the chocolatey.config file.

### Package Issues?

If you are having issues with a package, it is best to contact the maintainers of that package on the package site https://chocolatey.org/packages/jdk8/8.0.66 :

[image: Contact Maintainers link]

You can also read through the disqus forum at the bottom and post there as well. That will also reach the maintainers.

### Organizations Should Not Depend on the Community Feed

One last reminder - if an organization comes across this post - You should really read over why an organization should not depend on the community packages repository (aka https://chocolatey.org/packages) at [organization use of Chocolatey.org](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs#should-my-organization-depend-on-use-the-community-feed-httpschocolateyorgpackages). Copied here:

> First of all, it goes without stating that if you are a business and
>   you are using Chocolatey, you should think long and hard before
>   trusting an external source you have no control over (chocolatey.org packages,
>   in addition to all of the binaries that download from official
>   distribution channels over the internet). It is too easy to set up your [own private
>   feed](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/How-To-Host-Feed) where
>   you can vet packages and have complete control over the binaries and
>   what gets installed. This is what we recommend for businesses that use
>   Chocolatey in production scenarios (and what many of them do).

Comment: We wrote answers at the same time ;) I send information to maintainer.

Comment: I noticed! Never saw that before :)

Comment: Can  a super big package tell the choco installer to extend its timeout? eg: a package that is a 7GB download say and then takes a long time to install because it does a lot of work?

Comment: The user controls the timeout. The default timeout of 45 minutes is pretty big - however we found an issue where the download timeout was much less, and we've fixed it in the 0.9.10 beta to match the command timeout.

Comment: In 0.9.10, choco is also better at telling the user what happened and how to fix it up. You can also use read-host with a timeout (timeout is built into 0.9.10) asking the user if they have a large enough timeout and failing the package if they pick the non-default answer of no. Not the default because the default is to let the pkg continue when used in unattended operations.

Answer (score 2):

The package is broken, because (as you written) the URL `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u66-b18/jdk-8u66-windows-x64.exe` returns error page instead of `exe` file:

[image: error page]

The chocolatey didn't fail, because the package author:

- download file without using chocolatey tools (e.g. without checksum verification)
- didn't throw any error

I send an information to the maintainers.